# I am trying to import a file but it gives me exception : ORA-20001: Invalid Operation. while calling a stored procedure, how can i solve this

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am trying to import a file, but while calling the procedure I get an exception

> ORA-20001: Invalid Operation.

Stored procedure:

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  imp_pkg.isinmstimp(cpath => :cpath,
                     cfilename => :cfilename,
                     cusername => :cusername,
                     ndp_list_id => :ndp_list_id);
end;


 if (imp_module == "m_importisin")
            {
                //Call Procedure     
                s_dsnstr = o_Cls_Utility.utl_fnGetDSNStr(SessionCheck.s_sessiondpid);
                OracleConnect o_Cls_OracleConnect = new OracleConnect(s_dsnstr);
                o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_PreInit();
                o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cpath", parameter2);
                o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cfilename", parameter3);
                o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cusername", parameter4);
                o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Double_AddParameters("ndp_list_id", 1);
                int recordsInserted = o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure("IMP_PKG.ISINMSTIMP");


                o_Cls_OracleConnect.Dispose();             
            }
```

On the below line I get the exception :

```
int recordsInserted = o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure("IMP_PKG.ISINMSTIMP");
```

I have another bit of code which executes correctly, but throws an exception for stored procedure:

> value too large for column "CDSIL_MIGR"."ADDRESS"."ZIP" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)Row-no1

```
 if (imp_module == "m_impbankmaster")
            {
                //Call Procedure               
                try
                {
                    parameter2 = "d:\\imports";
                    parameter3 = "CD100621U.002";
                    parameter4 = "611";

                    s_dsnstr = o_Cls_Utility.utl_fnGetDSNStr(SessionCheck.s_sessiondpid);
                    OracleConnect o_Cls_OracleConnect = new OracleConnect(s_dsnstr);
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_PreInit();
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cpath", parameter2);
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cfilename", parameter3);
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Varchar2_AddParameters("cusername", parameter4);
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure_Double_AddParameters("ndp_list_id", 1);
                    int recordsInserted = o_Cls_OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure("IMP_PKG.BANKMSTIMP");
                    o_Cls_OracleConnect.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }             
            }
```

Comment: What part of "Store Procedure : value too large for column "CDSIL_MIGR"."ADDRESS"."ZIP" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)Row-no1" don't you understand?

Comment: `OracleConnect.CallStoredProcedure` doesn't look like something Oracle provides, so you should contact the author or vendor of that software to assist you in troubleshooting their code.

Comment: For problems with your client libraries, you should ask on Stackoverflow and tag for your library and language.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-20001: Invalid Operation.

This means you had some error, unfortunately either the procedure is not returning the full error stack to you, or your code is unable to display it. If you see the error stack, it will tell you which line the exception was raised on, then you can infer what the error could be. If this is all the code is returning to you, then it probably needs to be modified to return a better error message with useful information. Another way to try might be to call this procedure using sqlplus, with same parameters and then you will be able to see the error stack, which will be useful for debugging.

> value too large for column "CDSIL_MIGR"."ADDRESS"."ZIP" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)Row-no1

You seem to have a data issue, code is trying to insert/update 11 characters into ZIP column whose max size is 10 characters (perhaps on row number 1?). If you fix your bad data, you should be good to go. Since the procedure you are calling has a EXCEPTION block, it is actually suppressing actual error ORA-12899.